# Unity not see microphone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm use code

```
Debug.Log("Name: " + Microphone.devices.Length);
if (Application.HasUserAuthorization(UserAuthorization.Microphone))
      {
          Debug.Log("Microphone found");
      }
      else
      {
          Debug.Log("Microphone not found");
      }
```

And see 
Name: 0 and
Microphone found , but Discord and Other program see mecrophone . I'm tre reinstall drivers but don't help me.

Comment: Maybe you don't give it a permission.

Comment: Maybe, the mic is set to exculisve use and is already claimed by another process. Without any of your code there are also a lot of other "maybes".

Comment: I'm edit question

Comment: it's bug Nahimic audio